# Syntax Error in R when adding a loop to read multiple pdf pages

Tags: r, dataframe, pdftools

Can anyone help me to find where is my mistake in this piece of code?
This is what I am getting: "Error: unexpected '}' in "        }""

If I try to run only the chunk under the loop everything is fine but I need this to be process in 50 pages and then merged.

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidyr)
library(sqldf)

sDirectorio = "/Users/muribe/Desktop"

archivoPDF = pdftools::pdf_text(file.path(sDirectorio,"centros_votacion.pdf"))

n = 0

WHILE (n <8) {
        n=n+1
        
        vLineas = unlist( strsplit(archivoPDF[n], split = c("\r\n")) )

        dfDefinicionTabla = data.frame( Orden  = 1:9,
                                        Campo  = c("Codigo","Provincia","Canton","Distrito","JRVInicial","JRVFinal","TotalJRV","TipoCentro","CentroVotacion"),
                                        Inicio = c(1,8,21,36,75,86,97,104,127),
                                        Fin    = c(7,20,35,74,85,96,103,126,180),
                                        Tipo   = c("numeric","character","character","character","numeric","numeric","numeric","character","character"),
                                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

        dfTabla = data.frame()
       
        for (linea in 7:length(vLineas)) {
          
          dfFila = data.frame(n, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
          for (campo in 1:nrow(dfDefinicionTabla)){
            # campo = 2
            # Extrae cada uno de los campos de la linea  
            dfFila =cbind(dfFila, trimws(substr( vLineas[linea], 
                                                 dfDefinicionTabla[campo,]$Inicio, 
                                                 dfDefinicionTabla[campo,]$Fin), 
                                         which = "both") 
            )
            
          }
  
          colnames(dfFila)[2:(nrow(dfDefinicionTabla)+1)] = dfDefinicionTabla$Campo
          
          dfTabla <- rbind(dfTabla, dfFila)
        }

        }

print(dfTabla)``
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the only error you are getting. Seeing an uppercase `WHILE` seems unusual. The R keyword is lowercase `while`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I changed it to a 'repeat' loop and fixed other syntax errors Now is working.

```
{library(pdftools)
 library(tidyr)
 library(sqldf)

 sDirectorio = "~/Desktop"

 archivoPDF = pdftools::pdf_text(file.path(sDirectorio,"centros_votacion.pdf"))

 n = 1

 repeat { 
 if (n <50) {

vLineas = unlist( strsplit(archivoPDF[n], split = c("\r\n")) )

dfDefinicionTabla = data.frame( Orden  = 1:9,
                                Campo  = c("Codigo","Provincia","Canton","Distrito","JRVInicial","JRVFinal","TotalJRV","TipoCentro","CentroVotacion"),
                                Inicio = c(1,8,21,36,75,86,97,104,127),
                                Fin    = c(7,20,35,74,85,96,103,126,180),
                                Tipo   = c("numeric","character","character","character","numeric","numeric","numeric","character","character"),
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dfTabla = data.frame()

for (linea in 7:length(vLineas)) {
  
  dfFila = data.frame(n, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for (campo in 1:nrow(dfDefinicionTabla)){
    # campo = 2
    # Extrae cada uno de los campos de la linea  
    dfFila =cbind(dfFila, trimws(substr( vLineas[linea], 
                                         dfDefinicionTabla[campo,]$Inicio, 
                                         dfDefinicionTabla[campo,]$Fin), 
                                 which = "both") 
    )
    
  }
  
  colnames(dfFila)[2:(nrow(dfDefinicionTabla)+1)] = dfDefinicionTabla$Campo
  
  dfTabla = rbind(dfTabla, dfFila)
  
  assign(paste0("df",n),dfTabla)
  
} 
n = n + 1  } else break }

df <- rbind(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11,df12,df13,df14,df15
,df16,df17,df18,df19,df20,df21,df22,df23,df24,df25,df26,df27
 ,df28,df29,df30,df31,df32,df33,df34,df35,df36,df37,df38,df39,df40,
        df41,df42,df43,df44,df45,df46,df47,df48,df49)  

 head(df)}
```